# Strange PDF text extraction case

Tags: pdf

I'm looking at the following URL:
http://www.unisonagency.com/assets/news/unison_pr_mvsl.pdf

All of the open source text extraction tools I tried, give me the following for the heading:

```
uNISON LAuNCHeS MAGHReb VIRTuAL SCIeNCe LIbRARy: A NeW
PORTAL PROMOTING INTeRNATIONAL SCIeNTIFIC AND
TeCHNICAL COLLAbORATION
```

However, Adobe Acrobat Reader gives something more reasonable --

```
Unison Launch es Maghr eb Virt ual Sci enc e
Librar y: A New Portal Promoting Int ernational
Scientific and Technical Colla boration
```

The spaces are off, but character casing makes more sense. Any idea why the discrepancy is there?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is an example of "marked content" stream where BDC/EMC operators are used to annotate the stream with "ActualText" attributes, that's where the correct text is sitting.

Text itself is in UTF-16BE or PDFDocEncoding according to 7.9.2.2 in PDF 32000-1:2008

Answer (score -2):

The fonts are described inside of document. Text extraction tools interpret the description wrong or do assumption based on character code. Adobe products do it other way and interpret it right.